# how to use scope in angular directive 4

Tags: jquery, html, angular, angular-directive

Hello All I am using angular directive 1.6 to access ate attributes of a numeric textbox control 
here is my directive

```
app.directive('numerictextbox', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        require: 'ngModel',
        replace: true,
        template: '<input type="number" />',

        scope: {
            id: '@',
            ngModel: '=',
            min: '@',
            max: '@'
        },
        link: function (scope, element) {

            element.on('change', function () {
                scope.ngModel
                scope.$applyAsync();

            })
        }

    };
```

and here is my control

```
<numerictextbox id="txtid2" min="1" max="4" ng-model="txt2"></numerictextbox>
```

so the question is how can get the control attributes value in angular directive here is my **angular 4 directive**

```
@Directive({
        selector: '[number]'

})
```

how we can use scope in angular 4 directive
anybody please help

Comment: use ` @Input()` for getting data.

Comment: will you please elaborate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add properties into the Directive class with @Input() decorator

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[selectable]'
})
export class SelectableDirective{
    private el: HTMLElement;

    @Input('selectable') option:any;   
    @Input('first') f;
    @Input('second') s;

    ...
}
```

And in the template pass bound properties to your li element

```
<li *ngFor = 'let opt of currentQuestion.options' 
    [selectable] = 'opt' 
    [first]='YourParameterHere'
    [second]='YourParameterHere'
    (selectedOption) = 'onOptionSelection($event)'>
    {{opt.option}}
</li>
```

I have implemented in this way.This is working fine in my project.Please try it.

Comment: i want min value which is 1 in html so how can i access that value in directive

Comment: try this `min = "1"`

Comment: no not working i want to try to accessing min value in angular directive  which is 1 in HTML control

Comment: please go through the link. I have implemented the same way as given in docs and it works

Comment: would you make an an solution again  so i will mark it correct a

Comment: @Gaurav_0093 got your answer?

Comment: NO :-(  not able to get numeric control attribute values

Comment: can you try with string?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165809/discussion-between-gaurav-0093-and-swetansh-kumar).